# C# SqlDataReader, read multiples string in class

Tags: c#, sql

How can I allow my method read multiples string, so it can read the userID or email and prevent duplicates data.

```
       public bool usersduplicate(string username)
    {
        bool duplicate = false;
        string selectSQL = "SELECT username FROM Users";
        Connect();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSQL, conn);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            if (dr["username"].ToString().ToUpper() == username.ToUpper())
            {
                duplicate = true; 
            }
            
        }
```

this is how I check the data exists.

```
if (ctrls.checkclubexist(txtNameClubReg.Text) == true || txtNameClubReg.Text == "")
        {
        }
```

Comment: you should check a few tutorials on how to iterate data from db using c#

Answer (score 0):

You'd use multiple values the same way the method currently uses one value.  Essentially on any line of code where you currently use "username", you'd add "email".  For example...

Where your method currently accepts one parameter:

```
public bool usersduplicate(string username)
```

accept two:

```
public bool usersduplicate(string username, string email)
```

Where you currently select `username` from the data:

```
string selectSQL = "SELECT username FROM Users";
```

select both values (assuming column name here):

```
string selectSQL = "SELECT username, email FROM Users";
```

Where you currently compare one value:

```
if (dr["username"].ToString().ToUpper() == username.ToUpper())
```

compare both:

```
if (dr["username"].ToString().ToUpper() == username.ToUpper() || dr["email"].ToString().ToUpper() == email.ToUpper())
```

There's really nothing special to it.  Basically, when you're able to do a thing (in this case compare an input value to a data value) and you want to do that thing again, you would generally just repeat the exact thing you're already doing.